# Could I set my InnoDB MySQL Server session state for SQL_SAFE_UPDATES and INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT?

Tags: mysql, innodb, ubuntu, c#

Could I set my InnoDB MySQL Server session state for `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` and `INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT` using MySQL Workbench's  SQL Query window or MySQL Connection Navigator instead of in a c# Mono, .NET 4.5 MySQLCommand constructor on Ubuntu Linux 15.10?

If not, could I set my InnoDB MySQL Server session state for `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` and `INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT` using the MySQL server startup script? Where is that located on the Ubuntu Linux 15.10, and what mysql command line arguments should I put in the MySQL server startup scripts?

Here is my SQL script which I wish to run in the SQL Query window:

```
-- Current Database: `scdvr`
--

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `scdvr` 

USE `scdvr`;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

SET GLOBAL INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT = 2;
--
-- Table structure for table `ActionSequence`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ActionSequence`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `ActionSequence` (
  `ASID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `EAID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `SequenceOrder` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Toast` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SendToCentral` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LogAsEvent` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CameraGroupID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AudioAlertFile` varchar(800) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailAddresses` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ASID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ASID` (`ASID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `EAID` (`EAID`),
  KEY `IX_ActionSequence_EAID` (`EAID`),
  KEY `FK_ActionSequence_CameraGroups` (`CameraGroupID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ActionSequence_CameraGroups` FOREIGN KEY (`CameraGroupID`) REFERENCES `CameraGroups` (`CameraGroupID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ActionSequence_EventAction` FOREIGN KEY (`EAID`) REFERENCES `EventAction` (`EAID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you running?  [5.6 doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html) gives the details:

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` can be set (1) on the commandline, (2) in `my.cnf`, or (3) via `SET GLOBAL`.

`sql_safe_updates` can only be set via `SET SESSION` or `SET GLOBAL`.

Note that `SET GLOBAL` does not impact anyone *currently* connected (including yourself).  It will effect anyone connecting later, but before the next shutdown of mysqld.

`my.cnf` affects those who connect *after* the next restart.

Your question asks how to set them, but fails to say what the ultimate goal is, so I cannot recommend a particular approach.  (Do you care about Workbench?  Your C# connection?  Others currently connected?  Future connections?  What?)

I do not know whether Workbench re-connects between actions.  It probably does.  This implies that `SET SESSION` may not have any impact.

**Update** (based on update to Question)

```
SET GLOBAL INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT = 2;
Note: that SET will affect other users.
Now disconnect and reconnect.
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
and do the rest of your task.
```

But...  Neither of those settings impact a mere `CREATE TABLE`.  I assume you will proceed to do `INSERTs` and `UPDATEs`?

Side notes:  These two indexes are redundant and should be removed:

```
UNIQUE KEY `ASID` (`ASID`),
KEY `IX_ActionSequence_EAID` (`EAID`),
```

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY` is a `KEY`.

Why have both `ASID` and `EAID`?  Both are `UNIQUE`; both are `VARCHAR(64)`; either could be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. I am running MySQL Server 5.6. I just edited the original question to include my  SQL script which I wish to run in the SQL Query window: When does it take effect : before or after the next restart?

Comment: Thank you for your very useful update. The reason I put SET GLOBAL INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT = 2;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
in the SQL script is for INSERTS and UPDATES. Does your updated answer imply  that I have to disconnect and reconnect for it take effect?

Comment: The disconnect/reconnect is to get the `GLOBAL` value to be given to your `SESSION`.  (This was implied in my answer, but in a subtle way.)

Comment: (I think everything I said here applies to all platforms, not just Linux.  There _may_ have been changes over the versions of MySQL; check the page corresponding to the link I gave.)